# C'est quoi le féminin de « sauveur » ?

Tags: adjectifs, accord

Supposons que je m'adresse à une fille et que je veux lui dire qu'elle est la personne qui m'a sauvé.

Est-ce que je peux dire : « Tu es mon sauveur » ? et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Est-ce que je peux dire : « Tu es mon sauveur » ?

Oui.

> et pourquoi ?

Le mot *salvatrice* est plutôt utilisé comme adjectif:

- [Voir des exemples ici](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/salvatrice.html), mais notez,

  > Marie, médiatrice, consolatrice et co-salvatrice de l'humanité
- [Selon Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/sauveteur/71215/difficulte) il y a une nette différence entre « sauveur » et « salvateur »

  > Ne pas confondre ces deux noms.
  >
  > Sauveteur n.m. = personne qui prend part à une opération de sauvetage.
  >   Toujours masculin, même pour désigner une femme. Martine Balto, l'un
  >   des premiers sauveteurs à avoir approché les rescapés, témoigne.
  >
  > Sauveur n.m. et adj.m. = (celui) qui sauve, qui participe au salut de
  >   qqn ou qqch. **Toujours masculin, même pour désigner une femme : elle
  >   a été mon sauveur à ce moment difficile de ma vie.** « Le pilote qui
  >   sombre / Jette au phare sauveur un œil reconnaissant » (V. Hugo).
  >   Salvatrice sert de féminin à sauveur : une intervention salvatrice.

  Quand Larousse dit « Salvatrice sert de féminin à sauveur : une intervention salvatrice. » c'est comme adjectif.
- On dirait aussi, par exemple « Tu es mon docteur ou mon médecin » et non pas  « ma docteuse ou ma médecine ».

Votre question est marquée avec [adjectifs](/questions/tagged/adjectifs) et [accord](/questions/tagged/accord) ; mais, dans la phrase « Tu es mon sauveur », le mot « sauveur » est un nom commun (voir [noms](/questions/tagged/noms)) et pas un adjectif.

Comment: À l'usage courant (au Québec), j'entends souvent «sauveuse» être utilisé, à peu près aussi souvent que «sauveur». Au parler  le déterminant est parfois mis au féminin aussi, donnant «ma sauveur». Je ne l'ai jamais vu à l'écrit, par contre, alors je ne sais pas si un «e» est ajouté.

Comment: _docteuse_, non, _doctoresse_ par contre se dit.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Il peut se dire, mais le dirait-on? On vois ailleurs que « salvatrice » peut se dire : est-ce plus courant, plus correcte, ou bien un peu archaïque?

Comment: [On peut appeler une femme médecin "Madame la Doctoresse". Cette forme reste néanmoins minoritaire en France par rapport à "Madame le Docteur".](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/doctoresse)

Comment: _Doctoresse_ ne me choque pas (mais je suis d'accord qu'il est plus rare que simplement _docteur_ -- et je dirais même sur le déclin par rapport à mon enfance bien que ma perception n'est peut-être qu'un artefact de mon parcours). _Salvatrice_ comme nom sonne à mon oreille comme tout autre adjectif utilisé nominativement.

Comment: J'entends et utilise _doctoresse_ pour une femme médecin. Pour une titulaire d'un diplôme de doctorat hors médecine, je dis plutôt _docteur_.

Comment: @mouviciel D'accord. Mais je vois que par exemple les pancartes a l'hopital disent « Mme. le docteur *Nommée* ». Ma réponse ne change pas : on peut bien dire, « mon sauveur ».

Comment: @mouviciel Et certaines titulaires d'un doctorat (hors doctorat en médecine) se qualifient et mettent dans leur CV : docteure (avec le **e** à la fin). Et on parle aussi de docteures [en milieu médical](http://www.lepoint.fr/sante/quoi-de-neuf-docteure-22-08-2013-1747787_40.php) et pas seulement en [Belgique](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/docteure).

Comment: @Laure Je pense qu'il en va de même pour [professeure](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/professeure)

Comment: @Mina Professeure est beaucoup plus répandu que docteure.

Answer (score 1):

Je dirais tout simplement : « salvatrice ».

Voir TLFI : [salvatrice](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/salvatrice)

Comment: est ce que `salvatrice` est le féminin de `sauveur` ?

Comment: @Alji: Oui, j'ai mis le lien dans ma réponse. Plus particulièrement le point II.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour,

Aux remarques qui précèdent j'ajoute celle de [Grevisse-Goose](https://books.google.ch/books?id=SX0wDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA774&lpg=PA774&dq=sauveuse%20salvatrice&source=bl&ots=U3YHgSQ_v0&sig=R764eLOX0ZizMFOpqmY_obp_9eA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkucbCoefcAhWlK5oKHb_2AnYQ6AEwCXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=sauveuse%20salvatrice&f=false), pour qui les deux féminins de l'adjectif « sauveur », soit « salvatrice » et « sauveuse », coexistent. Ils relèvent cependant que le second est d'un usage rare.

Pour ma part, et en invoquant mon « intuition grammaticale », je dirais qu'une nuance de sens permet des les distinguer, sans pouvoir expliquer exactement laquelle. Ainsi outre le fait que l'adjectif se trouve ainsi « régularisé » (on n'a qu'un seul radical pour le même mot: « sauv- », et non les deux formes de même sens « sauv- »/ « salvat- »), je vois dans « sauveuse » quelque chose de moins définitif, de plus louvoyant que dans « salvatrice », qui m'apparaît par ailleurs comme plus précieux, plus pompeux (et pour cause, cette forme est très proche de son équivalent latin dont elle dérive, « salvatrix »).

J'espère vous avoir été utile.